# Modal Operator double keytrigger (RELEASE triggered twice on Ubuntu)

Tags: python, scripting, operator

here the smallest bit of code to show what I mean.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move an object with the mouse, example"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_test_operator"
    bl_label = "AA Run"

    modal_counter = IntProperty(default=0)

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if (event.type == 'MINUS') and (event.value == 'RELEASE'):
            self.modal_counter += 1
            print('triggered!', self.modal_counter)

        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            print('ended by finish')
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            print('ended by cancel')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.modal_counter = 0
        print('start')
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The output of this operator when you press the Minus key twice is this:

```
start
triggered! 1     <-- first press
triggered! 2     <-- first press
triggered! 3     <-- second press
triggered! 4     <-- second press 
ended by finish
```

What am I doing wrong? If i set it to listen for `event.value == 'PRESS'` it's OK, but it seems `'RELEASE'` is triggered twice?

Comment: Can confirm. If you print event.value, RELEASE is indeed printed twice to the console, while PRESS does only show up once.

Comment: Is there any reasoning behind this or is it a bug?

Comment: Cannot confirm. The code for me works well on Win7 in 2.74.0. I get only 1 line for RELEASE and same for PRESS (I do get multiple lines printed when holding the PRESS..but thats expected)

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14.04, maybe that's something to do with it.. If I thought it was a bug i'd report it, but it could also be my wonky modal code, I have yet to get my head around the various return sets

Comment: I tested this on Ubuntu 14.04, too.

Comment: Any idea how to bypass this problem? I tried to play with the timing, but then one must choose an arbitrary threshold: if time.time() - self.press_time > some_threshold

Comment: I went for PRESS in the end, it was just as good and didn't require an ugly kludge. Otherwise I'd consider using a _dict_ to store the last event obtained for the keys i'm interested in, if the last `event.value` for your key is the same as the current event.value then `pass` or something.

Comment: @NoamPeled i've given what I think might be a step towards dealing with the unwanted repeat press..(augmented my own answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was with the operating system /environment, and confirmed by pink-vertex. While this isn't a bug report, it may still be handy to keep around in case others experience it.

The behaviour had me stumped until I wrote the above code to localize what was happening.

This seems to be a long-standing bug in the windowing system that ubuntu uses: https://developer.blender.org/T21528 (dating:  Mar 9 2010)

---

## knowing it's broken isn't good enough.

@NoamPeled asks how one might get a working solution in the case of the windowing system throwing multiple repeat `event.values`, like `RELEASE` -- thus  increaseing the potential for the interface to behave in unexpected ways (ie a quick tap of a key could trigger release once or twice, but mostly twice -- at the very least the lack of consistency is the true issue then)

untested and verbose,

```
# somewhere at the top of your python file
# add any other keys you want to track
event_values = {'MINUS': None} 

# your modal operator code (snipped for brevity, see above in the question)

    def modal(self, context, event):

        # somewhere it makes sense
        if event.type in event_values.keys():
            if event.value == event_values.get(event.type):
                pass  # or some other passthrough/ignore
            else:
                event_values[event.type] = event.value
                # do some other useful thing
```